# creating a gif animated file in delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

```
gif := TgifImage.Create;
gif.Width := 100;
gif.Height := 100;
gif.AnimationSpeed := 500;
gif.Animate := true;
gif.add(image1.Picture.Bitmap);
gif.add(image2.Picture.Bitmap);
gif.add(image3.Picture.Bitmap);
gif.SaveToFile('gif.gif');
```

This loops just once and the speed is not 500?

How to make it loop and set the speed?

Answer (score 6):

Anders Melander, who wrote the original [TGIFImage](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/), has the following [answer](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/#faq_5).

> You need to add a “Netscape Loop” extension block to the first frame of your GIF.
>   The loop block must be the first extension you define for the frame or else it will not work.
>
> See the [Animate demo](http://melander.dk/articles/gifanimate/) for an example of how to build an animated GIF.

Here is a code excerpt from the [Animate demo](http://melander.dk/articles/gifanimate/):

```
// Add the source image to the animation
Result := GIF.Add(Source);

// Netscape Loop extension must be the first extension in the first frame!
if (GIF.Images.Count = 1) then
begin
  LoopExt := TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Result);
  LoopExt.Loops := 0; // Number of loops (0 = forever)
end;
```

You can view the [TGIFImage documentation here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/GIFImg_TGIFImage.html).

Comment: For clarity, you should specify the type of `LoopExt`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Gif:TGifImage;
begin
    //Setting the delay for each frame
    TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(Gif.Add(image1.Picture.Bitmap)).Delay := 300;
    TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(Gif.Add(image2.Picture.Bitmap)).Delay := 300;
    TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(Gif.Add(image3.Picture.Bitmap)).Delay := 300;
    //Adding loop extension in the first frame (0 = forever)
    TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Gif.Images.Frames[0]).Loops := 0;

    Gif.SaveToFile('gif.gif');
end;
```

Comment: ...until I realised it is broken. Apparently, the NS loop has to be inserted before the first GCE. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25480538/282848

Answer (score 1):

You can se an example of how to create an animated GIF, on my homepage www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/
There is also the original TGIFImage for Delphi 5 and for Delphi 6, Delphi 7, Delphi 2005, Delphi 2006, Delphi 2007, Delphi 2009.

Answer (score -1):

Need at least a timer and some flicker free methods.

See example in unit rxAnimate.pas from the RXLibrary 
(available free. Sources at SourceForge.net or http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/english.html).

There is also sources for a similar component at JVCL.

Comment: Oups .. .sorry. I did not see it was a TGifImage. I though of creating a gif animated component.