# Delphi TGIFImage animation issue with some GIF viewers

Tags: delphi, animation, gif, animated-gif, tgifimage

I have discovered that animated GIFs created using Delphi 2009's `TGIFImage` sometimes doesn't play correctly in *some* GIF viewers. The problem is that the animation is restarted prematurely.

Consider the following example:

```
program GIFAnomaly;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, Types, Classes, SysUtils, Graphics, GIFImg;

var
  g: TGIFImage;
  bm: TBitmap;

procedure MakeFrame(n: integer);
var
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to 256 - 1 do
    for y := 0 to 256 - 1 do
      bm.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := RGB((x + n) mod 255,
        (x + y - 2*n) mod 255, (x*y*n div 500) mod 255);
end;

var
  i: integer;

begin

  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  bm.SetSize(256, 256);

  g := TGIFImage.Create;
  g.Animate := true;
  for i := 0 to 499 do
  begin
    MakeFrame(i);
    TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(g.Add(bm)).Delay := 3;
    Writeln('Creating frame ', i+1, ' of 500.');
  end;
  TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(g.Images.Frames[0]).Loops := 0;

  g.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\test.gif');


end.
```

(This is the simplest example I could find that exhibits the problem.)

The output is a rather large animated GIF. In Internet Explorer 11, the entire 15-second 'movie' is played properly, but in Google Chrome the 'movie' is prematurely restarted after only about four seconds.

Why is this?

1. Is there something wrong with the output GIF file?
2. If so, is there something wrong with my code above, or is there a problem with `GIFImg`?
3. If not, what is the nature of the problem in the viewer? What fraction of the available viewers have this problem? Is there a way to 'avoid' this problem during GIF creation?

For the benefit of the SO user, the above code is a minimal working example. Of course, I wasn't creating these psychedelic patterns when I discovered the issue. Instead, I was working on a Lorenz system simulator, and produced this GIF animation which does play in IE but not in Chrome:

[image: Sample GIF animation displaying the issue]

In Internet Explorer 11, the model is rotated 360 degrees before the animation is restarted. In Google Chrome, the animation is restarted prematurely after only some 20 degrees.

- The Lorenz image **works** in Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17239, The GIMP 2.8.0, Opera 12.16
- The Lorenz image **does not work** in Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m, Firefox 26.0, 27.0.1, 31.0.

If I open a 'problematic' GIF in The GIMP and let GIMP (re)save it as an animated GIF, the result works in every viewer. The following is the GIMPed version of the Lorenz animation:

[image: Sample GIF animation that has been GIMPed]

Comparing the two files using a hex editor, and using [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF) as a reference, it seems, for instance, like the 'NETSCAPE' string is at the wrong place in the original (unGIMPed) version. It is somewhat strange, that even if I set the `width` and `height` of the GIF image, the corresponding values in the Logical Screen Descriptor are not there.

Comment: Oddly enough, ever time I run the above code (and the GIF is recreated), the length of the 'movie' in Google Chrome is changed (four seconds, three seconds, ten seconds, ...).

Comment: Compiling the test with XE6 and displaying in Chrome results in 15 seconds movie.

Comment: @LU RD: What about the GIF in the Q?

Comment: It looks as you describe, premature restart.

Comment: I see. Maybe there is an issue with the 2009 version, then.

Comment: Working in XE as well, I don't have D2010 and D2009 installed anymore.

Comment: When I look at the animation posted in the question using either IE9 or Google Chrome Portable I can only see model rotating for about 20 degrees. So I tried downloading the image file directly to my computer and opening it with every animation editing program that I have which supports GIF animation files all of them reported the file to be broken and thus fail to open it. SO I gues the image is either damaged or there is a new standard for GIF image that works in IE11.

Comment: @SilverWarior: But GIMP 2.8.0 displays the entire 360 degrees properly; it even lets me edit the 360 frames.

Comment: It seems like a header is missing. It also seems like at least Google Chrome gets happy if width and height are specified, in some way or another (property or header).

Comment: I also suspect a 'colour overflow' issue.

Comment: @LU RD: If you create the GIF in Delphi XEn, at what offset do you find the string 'NETSCAPE'?

Comment: Starts at offset 24.

Comment: First 48 bytes (Hex): `4749463839610001000177000021F904000300000021FF0B4E45545343415045322E3003010000002C00000000000100`.

Comment: +1 good Q. I wonder why you chose gif with its 256 colour limit. There must be a better choice for modern browsers that support html5.

Comment: The only thing I found was that the `AnimationSpeed` property was not set in D2009. So perhaps it could have a random value. I dug up a platform with D2009 and ran the test. It worked with a 15 sec animation sequence. First 48 bytes: `47 49 46 38 39 61 00 01 00 01 77 00 00 21 F9 04 00 03 00 00 00 21 FF 0B 4E 45 54 53 43 41 50 45 32 2E 30 03 01 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 00 01 00`.

Comment: @David: Because it is very easy (I thought) to implement, and in practice it works well. (And I have never tried to create animated GIFs before, so it was a bit of fun.)

Comment: The GIF format is so simple you may as well write your own streaming code. Anyway, I think your attractors would look much better with 8 bit RGB colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in TGIFImage's LZW encoder.

In some very rare circumstances the LZW encoder will output an extra zero byte at the end of the LZW steam. Since the LZW end block marker is also a zero byte, a strict GIF reader might choke on this or interpret it as the end of the GIF (although the end of file marker is $3B).

The reason some GIF readers can handle this is probably that GIFs with this problem was common many years ago. Apparently TGIFImage wasn't the only library to make that particular mistake.

To fix the problem make the following modification to `gifimg.pas` (change marked with ***):

```
procedure TGIFWriter.FlushBuffer;
begin
  if (FNeedsFlush) then
  begin
    FBuffer[0] := Byte(FBufferCount-1); // Block size excluding the count
    Stream.WriteBuffer(FBuffer, FBufferCount);
    FBufferCount := 1; // Reserve first byte of buffer for length
    FNeedsFlush := False; // *** Add this ***
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This appears to solve the issue. Thank you very much! Excellent answer!

Comment: But what happens if you call `function TGIFWriter.Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;` with a count that would make more than one call to `FlushBuffer`? That would block the writing.

Comment: AFAIR the encoder only writes a single byte at a time so it's will never become a real problem. Apart from that I agree that it smells. `FNeedsFlush` should be set inside the inner loop in `TGIFWriter.Write` instead of outside the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This turned out not to be the answer but I'm keeping it as the rule about the loop extension still applies.

---

The NETSCAPE loop extension **must** be the first extension:

```
var
  Frame: TGIFFrame;
...
for i := 0 to 499 do
begin
  MakeFrame(i);
  Frame := g.Add(bm);
  if (i = 0) then
    TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Frame).Loops := 0;
  TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(Frame).Delay := 3;
  Writeln('Creating frame ', i+1, ' of 500.');
end;
```

See: [The TGIFImage FAQ](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/#faq_5).

Apart from that I see nothing wrong with your GIF, but you could reduce the size a bit with a global color table.

Comment: Strange; It worked for me. I loaded the GIF, removed the GCE from frame 0 (thus making the loop extension the first) and saved it again (all using TGIFImage). I've just tried again and now it doesn't work. Will investigate further...