# How to create animated GIF files, from bitmaps, that are compatible with all media-players?

Tags: delphi, tgifimage

I am trying to create an animated GIF file from 8 bit-pixel bitmaps, and save it in a format compatible with Windows Media Player and VideoLan VLC, using Anders Melander's GIFImage.Pas library and Graphics system library.

The result, for now, is a file that contains no errors, but is not animated. How can I save a series of 8-bit-pixel TBitMap images to an animated GIF file?

Here is the test library:

```
Unit Prova;

(* This GIF saving test make a GIF file that can't be opened with
   Windows Media Player nor VideoLan VLC,
   because it seems to has some errors *)

Interface

Uses Graphics,GIFImage; (* Copyright: (c) 1997-99 Anders Melander *)

Procedure SaveBitmaps(Picture1,Picture2,Picture3:TBitMap
                      (* Same graphics resolution, 8 Bit Pixel + Palette *);
                      GIFFN:String);

Implementation

Procedure SaveBitmaps(Picture1,Picture2,Picture3:TBitMap
                      (* Same graphics resolution, 8 Bit Pixel + Palette *);
                      GIFFN:String);

Var GIFImg:TGIFImage;

Begin

 GIFImg:=TGIFImage.Create;

 GIFImg.AnimationSpeed:=30;
 GIFImg.Transparent:=False;
 GIFImg.Animate:=True;

 GIFImg.Width:=Picture1.Width;
 GIFImg.Height:=Picture1.Height;

 Try

  GIFImg.Add(Picture1);
  GIFImg.Add(Picture2);
  GIFImg.Add(Picture3);

  GifImg.OptimizeColorMap;
  GifImg.Optimize([ooMerge,ooCrop],rmNone,dmNearest,0);

  GIFImg.SaveToFile(GifFN);

 Finally

  GIFImg.Destroy;

 End;

End;

End.
```

I've created a .GIF animated file named "Treno.Gif" that contains 320 frames at 8 bit-pixel, 320 pixel width and 200 pixel width, with this method, and i've tested it on the web at:

[gif debugger world's simplest gif tool](https://onlinegiftools.com/analyze-gif)

The error that occours is:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'delay')

The file is:

[Treno.Gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNbm4TOkXVdV3k-wq9IcKxvUYIjmNhWb/view?usp=sharing)

It was created with a tool, named Anim32, which I am still developing;
you can find it at:

[Anim32 V.093](https://paolo-fassin.itch.io/anim32-a-graphic)

and help me solve any problems with the GIF format.

*WARNING: I Want to use GIFImage.pas unit, made by Anders Melander, Filip Larsen and Reinier Sterkenburg and
not GIFImg that it is included in Delphi 2007 package!*

The solution of Andreas Rejbrand:
[Delphi TGIFImage animation issue with some GIF viewers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476193/delphi-tgifimage-animation-issue-with-some-gif-viewers)
it is certainly valid, but, as I wrote, I need to use gifimage.pas and not gifimg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And VideoLan VLC does not supports animated GIF ?

Comment: The GIF animates just as expected in [Vivaldi 4.3.2439.44 x64](https://vivaldi.com/), [MPC-HC 1.9.8.137 x64](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/) and even the old [ACDSee 3.1 x32](https://www.acdsee.com/). It's a picture, not a video - a media player is primarily for video and audio - it wouldn't "play" [animated cursors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANI_(file_format)) either.

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25476193/282848

Comment: It is not necessary to **bold** every **other** word, **links**, short **phrases**, or **short parts of sentences** in **every paragraph**. Bold should be used only for text that needs to be emphasized, and if every other word in your post requires emphasis, you should rewrite it to remove that requirement. Over-use of formatting makes text harder to read and becomes quite annoying.

Comment: Respectable Mr. Andreas Rejbrand, your post give a good solution for my problem, thanks. When I will buy Delphi 2007 I will use GifImg unit instead GifImage!