# How to show gif on TSpeedButton

Tags: delphi, animated-gif

Following my previously asked question; [How do I display two images consecutively like a gif?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926334/how-do-i-display-two-images-consecutively-like-a-gif), I was told that I could create a `gif`.

Here is my reason: **tspeedbutton** does not accept `.gif` extension for me.

How can I add this?

```
btnNotification.Glyph.LoadFromFile(ICON_DIR + '/notification-active.gif');
```

I googled but couldn't find documentation because of Delphi.

Hello,

Actually i am trying to create Notification button. If there is no notification, its image is notification.bmp but if there is notification, it should be gif on tspeedbutton. I added a timer and polling the server, is there any notification for me ? in every 6 seconds, if yes i need to change bmp image to gif on tspeedbutton

Comment: Why don't you use `TImage` instead? `TSpeedButton` support only `.bmp` images. Load your `.gif` image and then `(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;`

Comment: @Sami it says unknown picture extension failed (.gif)

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Wild guess. Add VCL.gifimage to your uses and see if registering the extension does the trick.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Mybe you mean `Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg`

Comment: @Sami Sure, that's it. Using it leads to the extension being registered.

Comment: @Sami I think you will be interested in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this in a clean way I recommend that you build a new component. luckily there is a component that is a `TSpeedButton` and accepts any type of `TPicture` as its `Glyph` property, all what we have to do is to modify it to animate the Glyph if it was a GIF

So copy the unit of the `TNCRSpeedButton` from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758140/create-a-button-that-accepts-png-images-as-glyph)

go to the following procedure and add the lines to the code (or just replace this procedure with that one).

```
procedure TNCRSpeedButton.GlyphChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (FGlyph.Graphic <> nil) and (not FGlyph.Graphic.Empty) then
  begin
    FGlyphCoordinates.OnChange := nil; // Prevent multiple invalidates
    FGlyphCoordinates.X := (Width - FGlyph.Graphic.Width) div 2;
    FGlyphCoordinates.Y := (Height - FGlyph.Graphic.Height) div 2;
    FGlyphCoordinates.OnChange := CoordinatesChanged;
///// add these lines here ///////////////////////////////////
    if (FGlyph.Graphic is TGifImage) then
      begin
      (FGlyph.Graphic as TGifImage).Animate := True;
      end;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

now the component when recieved a `TGIFImage` as its Glyph it will animate it.

Comment: to the down voter the accepted answer is mine  and I'm the author of `TNCRSpeedbutton`, I just pratically gave the OP a peice of pie on a golden plate, all the Info is still on SO, so this does not violets any rule, What is wrong with my answer?.